# Fail to push to heroku

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, gemfile

Likely not the best way to migrate a rails 3 app to a rails 4 one, but I just deleted all the files (except for hidden .git files) and re-built a static webapp with no database or unit tests (`rails new testapp -O --skip-bundle -T`).  Everything works fine on my localhost.  I deleted then ran `bundle install` to re-create my Gemfile.lock.

I've also tested adding `config.serve_static_assets = true;` in config/application.rb but continue to see warning that "Detected Rails is not set to serve static_assets."

Here are the contents of my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

group :development do
  #gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor' # for heroku
end
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end
```

And here is the output I get when trying to push to Heroku:

```
me-mbp:testapp me$ git push heroku master
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 275, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (197/197), done.
Writing objects: 100% (211/211), 56.08 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 211 (delta 117), reused 3 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Detected Rails is not set to serve static_assets
       Installing rails3_serve_static_assets... done
-----> Configure Rails 3 to disable x-sendfile
       Installing rails3_disable_x_sendfile... done
-----> Configure Rails to log to stdout
       Installing rails_log_stdout... done
-----> Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.7
       Unresolved dependencies detected; Installing...
       Using --without development:test
       /tmp/build_25e2c7af-af3f-4901-8e75-4d3e12337bf8/Gemfile:2:in `evaluate': undefined method `ruby' for #<Bundler::Dsl:0x000000025d3c78> (NoMethodError)
              from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:7:in `instance_eval'
              from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:7:in `evaluate'
              from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:17:in `build'
              from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `definition'
              from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:225:in `install'
              from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
              from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
              from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
              from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
              from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
              from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
              from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
       FAILED: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler

 !     Push failed: failed to install gems via Bundler
 !     If the problem persists, see http://help.heroku.com and provide Request ID 25e2c7af-af3f-4901-8e75-4d3e12337bf8.
```

My full Gemfile.lock file shows a higher versioned bundler and rails:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.0.2)
      actionpack (= 4.0.2)
      mail (~> 2.5.4)
    actionpack (4.0.2)
      activesupport (= 4.0.2)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    activemodel (4.0.2)
      activesupport (= 4.0.2)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
    activerecord (4.0.2)
      activemodel (= 4.0.2)
      activerecord-deprecated_finders (~> 1.0.2)
      activesupport (= 4.0.2)
      arel (~> 4.0.0)
    activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
    activesupport (4.0.2)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4)
      minitest (~> 4.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.37)
    arel (4.0.1)
    atomic (1.1.14)
    builder (3.1.4)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.0.2)
    hike (1.2.3)
    i18n (0.6.9)
    jbuilder (1.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    jquery-rails (3.0.4)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.1)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.25.1)
    minitest (4.7.5)
    multi_json (1.8.2)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.5.2)
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.0.2)
      actionmailer (= 4.0.2)
      actionpack (= 4.0.2)
      activerecord (= 4.0.2)
      activesupport (= 4.0.2)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.0.2)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.2)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.2)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
    railties (4.0.2)
      actionpack (= 4.0.2)
      activesupport (= 4.0.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.1.1)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    sass (3.2.13)
    sass-rails (4.0.1)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    sdoc (0.3.20)
      json (>= 1.1.3)
      rdoc (~> 3.10)
    sprockets (2.10.1)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8)
    thor (0.18.1)
    thread_safe (0.1.3)
      atomic
    tilt (1.4.1)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    turbolinks (1.1.1)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (0.3.38)
    uglifier (2.1.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  coffee-rails (= 4.0.1)
  jbuilder (= 1.0.2)
  jquery-rails (= 3.0.4)
  rails (= 4.0.2)
  rails_12factor
  sass-rails (= 4.0.1)
  sdoc (= 0.3.20)
  turbolinks (= 1.1.1)
  uglifier (= 2.1.1)
```

Comment: this is also on the Heroku's bamboo stack and not cedar.  trying to migrate now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error happens when using an old version of Bundler that doesn't support the `ruby` method inside the Gemfile.

This is confirmed by the deploy output

```
-----> Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.7
```

Because the Cedar stack is updated, I assume you are using the Bamboo stack. You should upgrade to Cedar.

Comment: yeah, trying to migrate to cedar now.  only i lost all my css! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984600/cant-find-css-after-pushing-to-heroku