# Can't find CSS after pushing to Heroku

Tags: css, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

Everything works fine when I run locally, but fails when I push to heroku.  I've discovered that I need to modify all of the .css files in `app/assets/stylesheets/` to have `.css.scss` extensions and ensure my Gemfile contains:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
group :production, :staging do
  gem 'rails_12factor' # for heroku
end
```

Within my `.css.scss` files, I now use `image-url()` instead of `url()` to point to the fingerprinted image (fingerprinted and reorganized by heroku and asset compilation business).

in `app/views/layouts/mycontrollername.html.erb`:

```
<head>
  ...
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "path/to/css/file" %>
</head>
```

But I still can't find the right path.  When I look at the source, I see the path I expect except for the fingerprint: `path/to/css/file.css` instead of `path/to/css/file-somemd5hash.css`.  Note that the path does NOT include assets/path/to/css/file.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets

## EDIT

I've confirmed that there are no compiled css files on heroku in public/assets/.  There is one application.js file (it's empty) even though I have a .js.coffee file for each controller.  I have NO application.css, only a .css for each controller.

Comment: I don't have a great answer, but this workaround worked for me: in `config/environments/production.rb` comment out `config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?` and replace it with `config.serve_static_files = true` I wish I knew why this works though...

Answer (score 0):

This gem helped me get over it, which I guess will be merged into rails master soon:

gem 'sprockets_better_errors'

https://github.com/schneems/sprockets_better_errors